# Time Series chart to filter multi line chart(rendering multi lines for multiple data items)

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

What is the right way to filter multi line chart using a time series chart as filter?

I need a time series chart for my focus chart that it is shown the image below. Whenever I brush on time series chart my focus chart needs to be filtered with respect to time series chart.

The time series chart needs to contain only X axis and time as its dimension and it should be interactive with focus chart with respect to time.

```
var totalNumber = null;
// ------ main chart function -------
function makeCompetitiveGraphs(error, keywords_data) {
 errorHandle(error);

 cleanedData = getCompositeChartData(keywords_data);
 console.log("===", cleanedData);
 minDate = moment.min(cleanedData.timeStamp);
 maxDate = moment.max(cleanedData.timeStamp);

 margins = { top: 27, right: 27, bottom: 36, left: 54 };

 // create composite chart.
  var composite = dc.compositeChart('#competitiveChart');

 // create cross filter
 var cf = crossfilter(cleanedData.keywordData);

 // create dimensions.
 var keywordDateDimension = cf.dimension(function (dp) { return dp.date; 
  });
 var Group = keywordDateDimension.group();

 // compose for key words
 composeCharts = composeKeywords(dc, composite, keywordDateDimension);

 // create chart.
 composite
  .width(width())
  .height(height())
  .transitionDuration(1000)
  .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
  .ordering(function (d) { return d.value; })
  .elasticY(true)
  .elasticX(true)
  .margins(margins)
  .legend(
  dc.legend()
    .x(1100)
    .y(10)
    .itemHeight(16)
    .gap(8)
    .horizontal(false)
     )
  .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
  .brushOn(false);

 // compose the chart array.
 composite.compose(composeCharts);

// render the chart
 composite.render();

function getCompositeChartData(keywords) {
 let momentTimeStamps = [];
 let totalKeywordPerDay = [];
 let allKeywords = [];

 // clean data for d3js chart's
 keywords.forEach((kob) => {
  kob.sd.forEach((ob) => {
  allKeywords.push({
  name: kob.kn,
  total: ob.value.total__,
  date: new Date(moment(ob._id.mention_created_date_, "MMM-DD-YYYY-hh")._d),
});
momentTimeStamps.push(moment(moment(ob._id.mention_created_date_, "MMM-DD- 
 YYYY-hh")._d));
 totalKeywordPerDay.push(ob.value.total__);
 });
});
console.log("--------", allKeywords)

// apply date filter.
allKeywords = limiteDataToDateFilter(allKeywords);
return { "keywordData": allKeywords, "timeStamp": momentTimeStamps, 
"totalKeywordPerDay": totalKeywordPerDay };
}

function limiteDataToDateFilter(allKeywords) {
 cleanedDateWithDates = [];
 allKeywords.forEach(element => {
 if (moment(element.date).isAfter(moment().date(1).month(6)) &&
  moment(element.date).isBefore(moment().date(30).month(8))) {
  cleanedDateWithDates.push(element);
  }
});

 return cleanedDateWithDates;
}

function getReduce(keyword, keywordDateDimension) {
 return keywordDateDimension.group().reduceSum(function (dp) {
 return dp.name === keyword ? dp.total : 0;
 });
}

function composeKeywords(dc, composite, keywordDateDimension) {
 composeChartsData = []
 keywordsParams.forEach(keyword => {
 keyword.chart = dc.lineChart(composite)
  .dimension(keywordDateDimension)
  .colors(keyword.color)
  .group(getReduce(keyword.word, keywordDateDimension), keyword.word)
  .interpolate('basis')

  composeChartsData.push(keyword.chart);
 });

  return composeChartsData;
}
```

[image: focus chart for which I need time series chart to filter focus chart]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the articles about [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).  Please post your actual code instead of screenshots.

Comment: What is the expected behavior and what are you setting instead?

Comment: I am sorry, I think , now I edited the question in a proper way , Please fetch me the answer.Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried the [rangeChart](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html#rangeChart__anchor) feature? If so, what didn't work? Please include the complete code you tried that you think should work, if possible by [forking this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/ckf3d2cv/) and adding your code. Or if you can't use jsfiddle or bl.ocks, please include the rangeChart code and some sample data so that people can reproduce what you've done so far.

Comment: Sorry, it does take some time to learn how to ask a complete question - these are good skills to have for SO or anywhere!